# No response from firebase-element polymer component using browser-only app

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I am trying to get info to/from firebase using a browser-only app (i.e. only static files served, or from file://) with web components/polymer and firebase-element.

After adjusting paths, and adding --allow-file-access-from-files to my chrome startup I have eliminated all the console errors from the following html page, but now I just get nothing :( Not a sausage. Nor can I work out how to debug it. Do I need to add a simple login component or something? Is there a log somewhere I am missing? (I can't find one in firebase itself).

I tried adding a data change trigger event, but that doesn't seem to fire either :(

Many thanks in advance for ideas :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>eSS Firebase Test</title>
<!--
-->
  <script src="./components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="./components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="./firebase-import.html">

  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body unresolved>

    <firebase-element id="base" location="https://<--somefirebase-->.firebaseio.com/" log data="{{data}}" keys="{{keys}}" on-data-change="{{dataChange}}"></firebase-element>

    <h3>My Firebase Data</h3>

    <template repeat="{{key in keys}}">
      <p>{{key}}: {{data[key]}}</p>
    </template>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    dataChange = function(event) {
        console.log('data change!')
        console.log('change: ', event.detail.name, ':', event.detail.value);
            }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i didn't know components could be imported from a file:/// page...

Comment: Try to add an [auto-binding template](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding) around your body elements and adjust the script code accordingly.

Comment: I quickly tested a non-polymer local HTML page that accesses Firebase and that works fine in Chrome (even without `--allow-file-access-from-files`). Can you get it working without Firebase?

Comment: Before trying the above suggestions, I quickly set up a node server to deliver the files. Same (non) result. More experiments to follow :)

Comment: Have you tried @DirkGrappendorf's comment? {{}} doesn't work outside of Polymer.

Comment: @CletusW not yet, will do on Monday :)

Answer (score 1):

Polymer elements need a server to run from. Easiest way is to try simpleHTTP server from Python (assuming you have python installed)

Version 3 look like this

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Version 2 is different (tested with 2.7):

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

You can also use your existing LAMP stack if it's installed.

Looking at your code, you imported the wrong element. Instead of firebase-import you need to import firebase-element (which uses firebase-import internally). The code should look like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>eSS Firebase Test</title>
<!--
-->
  <script src="./components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="./components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="./firebase-element.html">

  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body unresolved>

    <firebase-element id="base" location="https://<--somefirebase-->.firebaseio.com/" log data="{{data}}" keys="{{keys}}" on-data-change="{{dataChange}}"></firebase-element>

    <h3>My Firebase Data</h3>

    <template repeat="{{key in keys}}">
      <p>{{key}}: {{data[key]}}</p>
    </template>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    dataChange = function(event) {
        console.log('data change!')
        console.log('change: ', event.detail.name, ':', event.detail.value);
            }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```